# Showing $\ell^p$ space is linear

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

from what I understand, it is easy to show that $\ell^p$ space is linear, without the famous inequalities (Minkowsky, Holder, etc.). The fact that is a metric space is not of interest for the moment. The question is first is about linearity.

What I particulary want to know is how to show that if $x,y\in \ell^p$, then also $x+y\in\ell^p$ for $p>1$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know of no proof easier than Minkowsky's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in the triangle inequality, you may substitute Minkowsk**i**'s inquality with the first step of its proof:

For $1 \le p < \infty$ the function $x \mapsto |x|^p$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$|x + y|^p = \Big| \frac12 \, 2\,x + \frac12 \, 2 \, y|^p \le \frac12 \,|2\,x|^p + \frac12 \,|2\,y|^p=2^{p-1}\,(|x|^p + |y|^p).$$
Hence, for $x,y \in \ell^p$ we find
$$\| x + y\|_p^p = \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i + y_i|^p
\le 2^{p-1} \, \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^p + |y_i|^p = 2^{p-1} \, (\|x\|_p^p + \|y\|_p^p).$$

The case $p = \infty$ is trivial.